# special character coming when i am using & and p

Tags: delphi

I dont know what exactly i have to type in title for this ,i tried my best

anyway coming to topic

I am making one acc checker for that purpose ,i am sending user and pass from my bsskinedit1 and bsskinedit2

here is my code

```
s:='http:\\site.com..premlogin='+bsskinedit.text+'&password='+bsskinedit2.text
```

but it giving some error ,then i used showmessage whats wrong with it then i came with strange result

see below

[image]

observer after 4  & and p combining together and appearing as a some new symbol :(

can any one tell me why its coming like this ?

Comment: If you want it to show properly in ShowMessage, you can `ShowMessage(StringReplace(s, '&', '&&', [sfReplaceAll]));`

But looking at the code shown, you are using backslashes, but URLs use forward slashes "/".  Also you may need to encode the values from the bsskinedit's, for instance to change spaces to %20, etc.  Indy should be able to do it with `...premlogin=' + TIdURI.URLEncode(bsskinedit.text) ...`

Comment: Although it looks like a "special character" — maybe an upside-down Cyrillic be (Б) — it's really not special at all. It's just an ordinary p with an underline.

Answer (score 4):

Your code (where you build the URL) is most likely correct (I guess the above has some typos?!), but when you display the URL in a label for instance, the `&` character is treated as indicator for an accelerator key.

> By Windows design, accelerator keys
>   enable the user to access a menu
>   command from the keyboard by pressing
>   Alt along the appropriate letter,
>   indicated in your code by the
>   preceding ampersand (&). The character
>   after the and sign (&) appears
>   underlined in the menu.

If you want to display the `&` character itself, you have to set your string variable to `&&`.

> By placing two ampesands together - you state that the character following the first one is *not* used as the accelerator - rather you actually want to get it (only one) displayed.

Just use your debugger if you want to see the real value that your string variables have, don't output them to a message box or the like... It may have side effects, as you can see.

**Regarding the URL you build:** I can't possibly know how it has to be correctly, but at least you should use the right slashes!

```
s := 'http://site.com...'
```

(All quotes from [delphi.about.com](http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2007/qt/and_ampersand.htm))

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Mef said, you can use [OutputDebugString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362%28VS.85%29.aspx) to add your string to the event log in its raw form, so you don't need to modify it before displaying it.  Delphi should capture those strings automatically if you're running from the debugger.  If you aren't running it from Delphi you can use [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) instead, which captures the messages from any running applications.